# Server side database query filtering and sorting from client data tables

Tags: javascript, database, filtering, client-server

I'm the author of a lit-based JavaScript web component library which includes some data models for data collections as well as user interface components like tables and lists. Currently it's all my own work, and I intend to release this open source before too long.

Currently my data table supports some complex user-defined sorting and filtering with collections, all conducted client side. I achieve this with my own JSON compatible hierarchical object type between the model and component. So far, this works well. I'm able to filter and sort via multiple criteria on multiple columns with a variety of typical data filtering operations.

However, some of the collections I'm accessing in one project are rather large, and existing client collections currently need to fetch all records in order to attend client side filtering & sorting. This isn't ideal and requires a significant amount of data to be transferred.

As a result, I'm looking to create a collection model that implements server side sorting, pagination and filtering. I am able to serialise my sorting and filtering structures to be processed server side, but this requires server side functionality to translate this further into SQL or similar.

Before I venture too far down this path, it feels like something that has been done before.

My google-foo has not been overly forthcoming, and I've not yet identified any widely used or current JavaScript libraries for communicating complex filters and sorting, or translating them into something useful for a range of server side databases. While my existing structures can adequately describe complex filtering and sorting, I'm not opposed to implementing something more standard.

Therefore this felt like a good question for the community before I start implementing everything myself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.